# RxJava emit only when emitter stops

Tags: android, rx-java2

In an Android app, I'd like to refresh the list only once the user has stopped selecting a list of items in a List. So in effect, I'd like to the observer to be informed only once the producer has stopped emitting for at least 500ms.

Right now I have something like the following:

```
Subject<Object> _bus = PublishSubject.create().toSerialized();

...
_bus.onNext(new Event());
...

_bus.delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe(event -> {
      // Do something with event
    }));
```

This is fine, except it emits at 500 ms intervals even if the source is still emitting. I'd like to wait for 500ms to see if the source has stopped calling `onNext()` and only then emit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you need debouncing with buffer. There is [article](http://blog.kaush.co/2015/01/05/debouncedbuffer-with-rxjava/) which should helper you.

And kick off sample from that article:

```
Observable<Object> tapEventEmitter = _rxBus.toObserverable().share();
    Observable<Object> debouncedEventEmitter = tapEventEmitter.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Observable<List<Object>> debouncedBufferEmitter = tapEventEmitter.buffer(debouncedEventEmitter);

    debouncedBufferEmitter.buffer(debouncedEventEmitter)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<List<Object>>() {
          @Override
          public void call(List<Object> taps) {
            _showTapCount(taps.size());
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to used debounce operator instead of delay eg.

```
_bus.debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
.distinctUntilChanged()
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.subscribe(event -> {
  // Do something with event
}));
```

Comment: That won't still do what I want. Plus denounce will miss out on emittances. I want to ensure all distinct values are processed